# How to get the text from this element with Scrapy ? :: text is not working

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

What are some other method can we use for text from element ?

```
>>> products.css('h2.entry-title').get()
'<h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="https://example.com/index.php/2021/12/12/your-20-with-few-clicks-from-stash/" rel="bookmark">Your $20 With Few Clicks From Stash</a></h2>'
```

but trying to get the text, **Your $20 With Few Clicks From Stash using**

> products.css('h2.entry-title::text').get()

```
>>> products.css('h2.entry-title::text').get()
>>>
```

is not working. Any suggestion?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the  desired text node `Your $20 With Few Clicks From Stash`  is under `a tag`. To get the correct output the css  expression would be as follows:

```
products.css('h2.entry-title a::text').get().strip()
```

## Implementation in scrapy shell:

```
In [6]: from scrapy.selector import Selector

In [7]: %paste
html_doc="""
<html>
 <body>
  <h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">
   <a href="https://example.com/index.php/2021/12/12/your-20-with-few-clicks-from-stash/" rel="bookmark">       
    Your $20 With Few Clicks From Stash
   </a>
  </h2>
 </body>
</html>
"""

## -- End pasted text --

In [8]: sel = Selector(text=html_doc)

In [9]: sel.css('h2.entry-title a::text').get().strip()
Out[9]: 'Your $20 With Few Clicks From Stash'
```